# customization card bootstrap 4 inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I use `bootstrap4` and I want to have a big card inside it, i want to put in each row 5 others cards like this screen.
This is my code

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="card w-100 mb-2">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Available products</h5>
        <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <div class="card mr-2 w-25 mb-2">
              <div class="card-header">34 products</div>
              <div class="mycard-footer">List of products</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mr-2 w-25 mb-2">
              <div class="card-header">34 products</div>
              <div class="mycard-footer">List of products</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mr-2 w-25 mb-2">
              <div class="card-header">34 products</div>
              <div class="mycard-footer">List of products</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

but i can't do it, any idea ?

Comment: I don't see 5 other cards in the image you provided...? Correct me if I'm wrong, but only 3 are there.

Comment: Hello @IslamElshobokshy , yes in the picture, there are only 3, but it is necessary 5 and in the code also I put 3, but it is necessary 5

Answer (score 0):

The width utilities of the cards that are inside are relative to the parent. Here is the bootstrap Doc for sizing utilities https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

There is no possible way to fit 5 cards in 1 row. Unless you add your personal styling in CSS and not use the sizing utilities.

Comment: Hello @Mudassir Ahmed, i can put 3 cards in 1 row, there is an example ?

Comment: You can put 3 in 1 row because they fit inside the parent `<div class="card w-100 mb-2">` . Here you are specifying `w-100` , the minimum `w`  sizing utility is `w-25` , which can only fit 4, not 5, and also it is relative to the parent.

Comment: Hello @Mudassir Ahmed , can you give me an example like because in my example, i doesn't have a good alignement

Comment: You are using sizing utilities, which are relevant to the parent class, so in your individual cards, you're as assigning width `w-25` which is relevant to the parent card whose width you've assigned as `w-100`. So 100% of the width of the parent card, and 25% of width in each individual card, you can only fit 4 at most, not 5. If you want to fit 5, add your own width in your CSS file, and don't use size utilities.